# How to get the full name of the local timezone?

Tags: go, timezone

For example the server timezone is "Europe/Madrid" and I do this:

```
now := time.Now()
fmt.Printf("%v", now.Location().String()) // prints "Local"

zone, _ := now.Zone()
fmt.Printf("%v", zone) // prints "CEST"
```

But I want "Europe/Madrid"

Timezones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

### Edit

Full cross platform (windows, linux, mac) answer provided here: https://github.com/thlib/go-timezone-local

All credit goes to [colm.anseo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218512/colm-anseo) and [MrFuppes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/mrfuppes) for providing the following answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68938947/175071
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68966317/175071

Comment: The result `"Europe/Madrid"` is ambiguous, there are at least a dozen different countries in the same zone.

Comment: Yes, but the device on which the go program is running has a very specific timezone running, in this case "Europe/Madrid", so I don't see any ambiguity here, I just want to know what timezone is being run.

Comment: Not sure what OS you are using - but a `zoneinfo` file just stores offsets and the shortname e.g. `CEST` - it does not contain the user-friendly long name. The OS loads this info by filename *path*. The path suffix contains the long-name.

Comment: I use windows, linux and mac, running @colm.anseo s solution on linux gives me `../usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Madrid` which is exactly what I want... but I want it in go.

Comment: @icza time zones such as IANA's "Europe/Madrid" are not specific to countries but geographic regions. The ambiguity starts when you're using [abbreviations](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) like "BST" or "IST".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IANA timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are available on most OSes (*). The `Go` standard library ships it as well:

```
runtime.GOROOT() + "/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip"
```

The selection of a timezone by *name* and whether this name is recorded anywhere is left up to the OS:

```
ls -al /etc/localtime

# MacOS
/etc/localtime -> /var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/America/New_York

# Linux
/etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York
```

so in the above cases the name may be inferred.

Note: `Go` uses `/etc/localtime` by default for the local OS time ([timezone.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/time/zoneinfo.go;l=77)) - but this can be overridden with the `TZ` environment variable.

So one could infer the name of the local OS timezone, via the symlink target path like so:

```
// tz.go

//go:build !windows
// +build !windows

const localZoneFile = "/etc/localtime" // symlinked file - set by OS
var ValidateLocationName = true        // set to false to disable time.LoadLocation validation check

func LocalTZLocationName() (name string, err error) {

    var ok bool
    if name, ok = os.LookupEnv("TZ"); ok {
        if name == "" { // if blank - Go treats this as UTC
            return "UTC", nil
        }
        if ValidateLocationName {
            _, err = time.LoadLocation(name) // optional validation of name
        }
        return
    }

    fi, err := os.Lstat(localZoneFile)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to stat %q: %w", localZoneFile, err)
        return
    }

    if (fi.Mode() & os.ModeSymlink) == 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("%q is not a symlink - cannot infer name", localZoneFile)
        return
    }

    p, err := os.Readlink(localZoneFile)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    name, err = inferFromPath(p) // handles 1 & 2 part zone names
    return
}

func inferFromPath(p string) (name string, err error) {

    dir, lname := path.Split(p)

    if len(dir) == 0 || len(lname) == 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("cannot infer timezone name from path: %q", p)
        return
    }

    _, fname := path.Split(dir[:len(dir)-1])

    if fname == "zoneinfo" {
        name = lname // e.g. /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan
    } else {
        name = fname + string(os.PathSeparator) + lname // e.g. /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo
    }

    if ValidateLocationName {
        _, err = time.LoadLocation(name) // optional validation of name
    }

    return
}

// tz_windows.go
//go:build windows
// +build windows

func LocalTZLocationName() (string, error) {
    return "", fmt.Errorf("local timezone name inference not available on Windows")
}
```

---

(*) for `Windows` according to the Go source ([zoneinfo_windows.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/time/zoneinfo_windows.go;l=15)), zone info is loaded from the Go standard library, due to:

```
// BUG(brainman,rsc): On Windows, the operating system does not provide complete
// time zone information.
// The implementation assumes that this year's rules for daylight savings
// time apply to all previous and future years as well.
```

the Window's registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
```

stores the local timezone - but does not appear to store the long form location name:

```
TimeZoneKeyName=Eastern Standard Time
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you, would be good to see the way to get the timezone on windows for completeness sake.

Comment: If no answer is found in the next few days, would it be ok with you if I create a function in go to get the timezone using your solution for all platforms and post it as  an accepted answer for this question?

Comment: Brilliant! The only thing missing would be to add an example of how to use your `LocalTZLocationName` function and also handle the `TZ` environment variable gracefully.

Comment: fixed bug where zone names may be one or two-parted. Also added support if `TZ` env var is set.

Comment: @colm.anseo I hope you don't mind but I've put your answer together into one repo: https://github.com/thlib/go-timezone-local

Answer (score 1):

**On Windows**, the procedure also isn't overly complex. As [mentioned by @colm.anseo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68938947/10197418), you can read the respective registry key to get the time zone name that Windows uses. Then map that to the appropriate IANA time zone name.

***read tz from registry***

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)

var winTZtoIANA = map[string]string{
    // just includes my time zone; to be extended...
    "W. Europe Standard Time": "Europe/Berlin",
}

func main() {

    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer k.Close()

    winTZname, _, err := k.GetStringValue("TimeZoneKeyName")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("local time zone in Windows: %v\n", winTZname)

    if IANATZname, ok := winTZtoIANA[winTZname]; ok {
        log.Printf("local time zone IANA name: %v\n", IANATZname)
    } else {
        log.Fatalf("could not find IANA tz name for %v", winTZname)
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can **read the output of `tzutil /g`**:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("tzutil", "/g")
winTZname, err := cmd.Output() // note: winTZname is []byte, need to convert to string
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

You can find a comprehensive [mapping here](https://github.com/MrFuppes/go-timezone-local/blob/main/tzlocal/tzmapping.go). It's based on [Lennart Regebro's tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) package that solves the given question in Python.

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you a lot for this

Comment: @TimoHuovinen I found another approach, using Windows' `tzutil` command. I've added it [here](https://github.com/MrFuppes/goGetLocalTZname/blob/main/gettzname.go). It's a nice way to get this to work on multiple platforms without having to compile for them individually.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I've put your answer together into one repo: https://github.com/thlib/go-timezone-local